# TortoiseSVN dropping fully qualified domain name

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm working with a client's TortoiseSVN repository and they have multiple domains in place due to mergers with other organizations. In order to access their repository from the domain I am on, I have to fully qualify the name of their repository server.

However, halfway during the checkout I started to receive errors for subdirectories saying

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'http://servername/svn/dev/etc'
No such host is known.
```

What I notice immediately is that the name provided is not fully qualified, which I believe is causing the error. However, I'm not sure how to fix that as I wonder if it's some kind of internal repository reference to subfolders?

Comment: Is there a external repository defined in there perhaps? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely there is an [external repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) defined in one of the subdirectories, using a hardcoded non-relative address.

This can be changed for future changesets, but will pose a problem for older changesets, if you need to check out an older version where the incorrect externals definition is still in place.

One way, if it's only the host name/address that is wrong, would be to temporarily add an entry to your hosts file with the incorrect name but correct IP address. I believe this should be enough.

Comment: Adding the IP address of the server with the unqualified server name to the hosts file worked to resolve this issue.